# How to use "union all" in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two queries.

**The first**:

```
SELECT CreatedOn, COUNT(*) AS locationNonProcessed
FROM Table1
WHERE IsActive = 0
GROUP BY CAST(CreatedOn AS DATE), CreatedOn
```

**The second**:

```
SELECT CreatedOn, COUNT(*) AS locationProcessed
FROM Table1
WHERE IsActive = 1
GROUP BY CAST(CreatedOn AS DATE), CreatedOn
```

How should I use `UNION ALL` with these queries?

Comment: what you have tried and what issue you are facing?

Comment: No need to UNION ALL. Simply include IsActive in GROUP BY clause and in SELECT list.

Comment: What results do you want?  `UNION ALL` is pretty simple.  Write the two queries and put `UNION ALL` between them.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you really want `union all`.  That is trivial to implement and results in not very sensible results (you won't know which count is which).

I suspect you want conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT CAST(CreatedOn AS DATE),
       SUM(CASE WHEN IsActive = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS locationNonProcessed,
       SUM(CASE WHEN IsActive = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as locationProcessed
FROM Table1
GROUP BY CAST(CreatedOn AS DATE);
```

Note the fix to the `SELECT` and `GROUP BY`.

If `IsActive` takes on only the values of 0, 1, and possibly `NULL`, this can be simplified to:

```
SELECT CAST(CreatedOn AS DATE),
       SUM(1 - IsActive) AS locationNonProcessed,
       SUM(IsActive) as locationProcessed
FROM Table1
GROUP BY CAST(CreatedOn AS DATE);
```

Comment: I think we have to include IsActive in group by as suggested by @jarlh

Comment: @SandipPatel . . . That is another alternative.

Comment: @SandipPatel it depends if you want the count as a separate row, or an extra column. OP might choose this answer becuase they didn't know how to get it in their original question

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT createdon, IsActive, COUNT(*) AS locationProcessed
FROM Table1
WHERE IsActive in (0, 1)
GROUP BY CAST(CreatedOn AS DATE), CreatedOn, IsActive
```

`GROUP BY CAST(CreatedOn AS DATE), CreatedOn` is odd to me.  That is not different than `GROUP BY CreatedOn`.

Comment: That `WHERE` clause might actually be not needed because it's boolean. Of course if OP doesn't have `NULL`s.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT createdon,
       SUM(CASE WHEN IsActive = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS locationNonProcessed,
       SUM(CASE WHEN IsActive = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as locationProcessed
FROM Table1
GROUP BY CAST(CreatedOn AS DATE), CreatedOn;
```